# Added a Custom field to media elements, where do I assign values in administration view

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Added a Custom field to media elements, where do I assign values in administration view?

Can't find the field to set the value for the image object.

Expected to set it for an image object globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed with Version 6.4.17.0

https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-22512?products=SW-6&edition=community,professionalEdition,enterpriseEdition,shopwareRise,shopwareEvolve,shopwareBeyond&projects=all&type=1,4&status=open,inProgress,done&search=NEXT-22512

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Find the file after navigating to [Content > Media](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/content/media). Select the file and in the sidebar to the right you should find the the custom fields sets at the very bottom.

Update: As of today there is an issue with custom fields in the media module, that was already fixed but [not yet released](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/changelog/_unreleased/2022-09-23-fix-custom-field-in-the-media-display.md).

Comment: This is where I expeted to find the custom fields sets, but it is not showing up.

Comment: Yes, I am also not able to find the custom field section in the sidebar. Tested in SW version: **6.4.14.0 & 6.4.16.0**

Comment: This was apparently fixed recently but not yet included in a release: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/changelog/_unreleased/2022-09-23-fix-custom-field-in-the-media-display.md - Should be included in the next minor release.

Comment: Could you keep us posted on that issue @dneustadt?